# Accessing property of parent in nested object

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring some JS code and need to access Objects like

```
Object1.Object2.IsValid();
```

this is what I have right now.

```
function _Object1(object) {

    this._object1 = object;

    this.Object2= new _Object2();

    function IsValid() {
        // tests here
    }
}

function _Object2()
{
    function IsValid() {
        // tests here but needs to use Object1 property above.
    }
}
```

Only problem being, I am not sure how to access Object1 in Object2 without passing any parameter. Nesting Object2 in Object1, perhaps?

Edit: I am tring to implement OOP in JS, which is like reinventing the wheel, but want to try it for now :)

I will explain the question in terms of OOP:

I have a class `_Object1` and it has a method `IsValid()`. `_Object1` also has a property `Object2` which is of type `_Object2`.

Now, `_Object2` also has method named `IsValid()`. But here is a catch, `_Object2.IsValid` need the value of `_Object1` for tests.

For the above code if I do:

```
var Object1 = new _Object1();
```

I can simply call `Object1.Object2.IsValid()` for the result. Isn't it?

Disclaimer: I have been using JS for sometime now, but never had to dabble with things like these.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to answer your question. What exactly are you trying to do? "Trying to access Object1 in Object2" is not specific enough. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: That's all I have, updating the question with what else I can come up with.

Comment: can use a closure+that combo, or pass the instance, dealer's choice.

Comment: Like linstantnoodles, I'm unclear on the context. Are you struggling with execution scope? There's good documentation on this, and I want to share them here: __Professional JavaScript for Web Developers__, by N. Zakas handles Scope (Chapter 4 in 3rd edition). Also, you can find more on [function scope on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). If you want, you could take advantage of [Object inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `_Object2` what it needs:

```
function _Object1(object) {

    this._object1 = object;

    this.Object2= new _Object2(this);

    function IsValid() {
        // tests here
    }
}

function _Object2(parentObject)
{
    function IsValid() {
        // parentObject refers to the _Object1 that created this object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not want to pass any parameter to Object2 but it seems thats gonna save me some headache.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is impossible, unless you are willing to pass the data in to the object.

Just because your `_Object2` instance has been created inside the `_Object1` constructor, it does not automatically have any reference to the data of your `_Object1` instance.  You would have to tell the `_Object2` instance about the `_Object1` values either in the constructor function or via some other method:

```
function _Object2(parentObject) { /* ... */ }
// or
_Object2.prototype.setParent = function(parent) { /* ... */}
// or
myObject2.parent = this._object1;
```

Comment: I Totally agree, I was not sure what all information can `this` carry with it. So this is just usual programming :). Thanks.